# Why is FastDirectoryEnumerator so fast but handling its exceptions are so slow?

Tags: c#, search, directory, enumerator

I had an issue where the following was checking for files that existed but not alerting me to the fact it was skipping over directories (stemming from root _rootDirectory) that don't exist:

```
_matchingFiles = FastDirectoryEnumerator.GetFiles(_rootDirectory, _searchItem, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

But when I do the following to store directories I'm monitoring that can't be found, it's very very slow:

```
try
{
    _matchingFiles = FastDirectoryEnumerator.GetFiles(_rootDirectory, _searchItem, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    var noMatchesFoundString = new List<string>
        {
            "Root: " + "<" + _rootDirectory + ">, Search Item: " + _searchItem,
            "Could Not Be Found",
            _monitoringID
        };

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" - ", noMatchesFoundString));

    StaleItems.AddRowToTable(noMatchesFoundString);
}
```

Is there a better way to store the exceptions of unfound files from FastDirectoryEnumerator? Is there another method I should use before FastDirectoryEnumerator if it wasn't intended to handle such behavior quickly?

Comment: Holup... what is `FastDirectoryEnumerator` and where did you find it, its not part of the BCL

Comment: If it's [this library](https://uframe.github.io/api/uFrame.Editor.Core.FastDirectoryEnumerator.html#uFrame_Editor_Core_FastDirectoryEnumerator_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_SearchOption_), the indicated exceptions relate to the input to the method, not the result of the search. At least from looking at the docs, I wouldn't expect you to get an exception.

Comment: What does `AddRowToTable` do? Incidentally, any particular reason you are newing up a List with one item in it and then `string.Join`ing it

Comment: Exceptions are slow in general, some will propagate from the inner cockles (ring 0) of the operating system. However, its likely what you are doing in the catch that is causing you the issues here. Store the metadata of what you need in a list. then update the UI when finished

Comment: @00110001 how can I find a file that doesn't exist without handling an exception in the attempt to find its existence?

Comment: So is the problem, that the directory `_rootDirectory` doesn't exist sometimes? Maybe if you edit this question with just a little more specify it might help someone answer.

Comment: @00110001 that's correct, when _rootDirectory doesn't exist. Updated the post per your suggestion to clarify that point, thanks.

Comment: You could use `Directory.Exists`, note its not bullet proof though, meaning some other process or thread might delete or add such a directory